# "Tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str" when loading Tensorflow Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I'm trying to load the MNIST dataset, but I'm getting

> TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

mnist_dataset = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_dataset['train'], mnist_dataset['test']
```

This line is giving me the error:

```
mnist_train, mnist_test = mnist_dataset['train'], mnist_dataset['test']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include `with_info=True`, you need to unpack accordingly:

```
mnist_dataset, info = tfds.load(name='mnist', with_info=True, as_supervised=True)
```

The way you did it, `mnist_dataset` is a tuple containing a 2-item dictionary and a `tfds.core.DatasetInfo` object:

```
(
    {
'test': <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((28, 28, 1), ()), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>,
'train': <PrefetchDataset shapes: ((28, 28, 1), ()), types: (tf.uint8, tf.int64)>
    },
    
tfds.core.DatasetInfo(name='mnist', etc)
)
```